# NFC Controller NXP PN548 tag detection stopped working

Tags: controller, serial-port, nfc, polling, hal

I have been messing with PN544 settings directly to the serial interface, without any code wrapper or driver used. My problem is that I must have set some value to some register that I am not aware of, that caused this issue:

Whenever I put it in **polling mode** for card reading, it doesn't detect any tags, unless I put 2 tags together close to the device. (!)

Before I did this, I was getting notifications fine from the serial port of type "61 05 17 01 01 02 00 ff [rest of tag info]" for each individual tag.

```
[TX]: 20 00 01 00 (RESET_NCI)
[RX]: 40 00 03 00 10 00 (OK)
[TX]: 20 01 00 (INIT_NCI)
[RX]: 40 01 16 00 03 0E 02 00 05 00 01 02 03 80 02 80 02 FF 02 00 04 0D 02 01 23 (OK)
[TX]: 2f 02 00 (PROPR_FEATURES)
[RX]: 4F 02 05 00 00 00 B1 AE (OK)
.... Default init packets used as before the issue
.... Enter polling mode:
[TX]: 20 02 05 01 a0 39 01 01
[RX]: 40 02 02 00 00 (OK)
[TX]: 20 02 0e 04 18 01 01 32 01 20 50 01 00 00 02 2c 01
[RX]: 40 02 02 00 00 (OK)
[TX]: 21 03 0d 06 00 01 01 01 02 01 80 01 81 01 82 01 
[RX]: 41 03 01 00 (OK)

^ At this point it should receive notifications when a tag approaches, 
like it used to before I messed up.
```

I must have either set some register that sets the minimum amount of tags required to send a notification, or maybe messed with the antenna settings and is not powered enough.

I have managed to read and take all registers from another same device, but only for registers 0x00 to 0xff, and A0 00-AO FF. There has to be another registers range I am missing.

I couldn't find much info about this not only for PN548, but neither for 544/547 that have similar registers. I tried to find all the changes I set and set them back, but still it detects only two tags, one is not enough.

Does anyone know of the required registers that I could try changing?
I am interested in the actual data packet , not any functions from libraries. Any hints would be welcome, like changing the antenna power, setting tag technology detection, or maybe number of tags required?

A command that returns all registers would also be useful, I have another working device from where I can copy all settings, but I only know how to read/write NCI_CONFIG_PARAM (0x00-0xff) and NXP_CONFIG_PARAM registers, (0xA000-0xA0FF). If you know how to get all other registers it would also be helpful.

I am only interested in the data packets I can send/receive to serial port, not any library or driver functions.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, it was an antenna RF_TRANSITION_CMD setting.

I read all values from another device and passed them to mine, works fine now.